# Python ModuleNotFoundError with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I got a strange issue and have no idea about the reason.

As you can see from the picture, folder `fuzzier` and `parser` are under the same parent folder, and both of them have the file `__init__.py` (both empty because I am not using `from xxx import *`, and code is based on Python 3.6).

And in another module (under the same parent folder with `fuzzier` and `parser`), there is a file doing some import like this:

```
import fuzzier.jison
import parser.annoying_char
```

The first line is good, but the second line is with an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parser.annoying_char'; 'parser' is not a package`

[image]

I wasted hours on this and wish someone can help with this, Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your file paths? What does it show? Where are you running this file from?

Comment: somehow I just changed the folder name `parser` to something else, e.g. `_parser` and the issue is gone, not quite sure why

Comment: see my answer, I deleted it earlier because it didn't make sense. But I guess I was right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parser is an in-built library in Python.
Python is trying to find `annoying_char` inside that library instead of your module. 
You should use some other name.

Source - https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html